# Sqlite3 CASE statement in a Subselect

Tags: sqlite, subquery, case

In a poll application I have this working SQL query:

```
SELECT options.id, options.question_id,
CASE WHEN (options.position = 0) THEN 999 ELSE options.position END AS position,
(SELECT translations.text_1 FROM translations WHERE translations.item_model = 'options' AND translations.language = 'fr' AND translations.item_id = options.id) AS translation
    FROM options
WHERE options.question_id IN (1)
ORDER BY options.question_id, position
```

You see, I select the options belonging to a question and, for each option, the corresponding translation in the given language
At the moment, if there is not the translation for the given language, the `translation` field is null.

(please mind I can not replace subquery with a classic join statements

To keep things simple, I'd like to show a `'missing translation'` message whenever the translation is not found.
I thought this query would work, but it's not:

```
SELECT options.id, options.question_id, options.is_freetext,
CASE WHEN (options.position = 0) THEN 999 ELSE options.position END AS position,
(SELECT
    CASE WHEN (translations.text_1 IS NULL) THEN
        'missing traslation' -- but I could do another query here to retrieve something else
    ELSE
        translations.text_1
    END
FROM translations WHERE translations.item_id = options.id AND translations.item_model = 'options' AND translations.language = 'fr') AS translation
    FROM options
WHERE options.question_id IN (1)
ORDER BY options.question_id, position
```

Indeed, if there are not translations for the given language, I get `null` fields instead of default message. But if there are translations, I get them!
What's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that this:

```
WHERE translations.item_id = options.id AND translations.item_model = 'options' AND translations.language = 'fr'
```

for some reason returns no rows when there is no translation so the CASE statement is not even executed so you get NULL? 
You must make this check.

Comment: Ops, you are right: since I have no translations in that language, the WHERE condition returns no rows, hence the CASE is not even executed... I thought it still returned null value, as in the first query I posted (without CASE), but I guess it ain't so...